# Maximum request length exceeded when uploading file to IIS 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I am getting : Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded. I am using Windows 2012 IIS. I checked the settings in IIS and it is set to 30000000. My file I am uploading is 20mb. I tried adding the code below to the web.config file. I have uploaded smaller files with no issues. Any other ideas?

```
<system.webServer>

   <security>

      <requestFiltering>

         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />

      </requestFiltering>

   </security>

</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to set maxRequestLength like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

maxRequestLength indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET. The size specified is in kilobytes. The default is 4096 KB (4 MB).

Answer (score 0):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="43000000" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```

40 mb

all code system.web

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" >
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="43000000" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
```